# <div> element not showing full size in twitter bootstrap tabbable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Google Chart that displays fine in its own page `/graph/map_freq` but is sized down when I display it as a tab content.

Here's the tabbable code:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="map_freq">
<%= render "graph/map_freq" %>
</div>
```

Here's the code in graph/map_freq.html.erb:

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I am pretty sure this is related to tabbable component of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You shall mark it up like so...

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="map_freq">
     <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#featured-members">Your Tab Name</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="yourId">
     <div id="map_freq" class="tab-pane active fade in">
       Your Content Here.
     </div>
</div>
```

The code shall output a page similar to [THIS ONE.](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/625/3105008099.png)

Comment: Thanks but I got it to work. Turns out maybe twitter bootstrap doesn't repect a <div> element's size passed in style. So I had to pass the chart size in the chart options itself.